# How to specify a historic date in python datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a code which is written to be executed for the current date and time only. Now I need to execute it for a historic date so I need to replace the date variables mentioned below:

```
curr_month = dt.datetime.now()
```

AND

```
today_day = dt.datetime.today()
```

OUTPUT

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2, 22, 36, 9, 155118)
```

What format can I use to specify a historic date so that it would be in a DateTime datatype in the exact format mentioned above?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  What do you mean by "a historic date"?  Give an example, as well as the code you tried for specifying that date.  If your "historic date" is within that range supported by `datetime`, then you should have no trouble to do this from any of the many available tutorials and examples on line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime object you reference has a constructor. Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime):

```
my_historic_date = dt.datetime(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, *, fold=0)
```

If you wanted [June 3, 2017 at 9:28am](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/adventure/features/athletes/alex-honnold/most-dangerous-free-solo-climb-yosemite-national-park-el-capitan/#:%7E:text=Rock%20climber%20Alex%20Honnold%20training,Saturday%2C%20June%203%2C%202017.) you would do

```
free_solo_date = dt.datetime(2017, 6, 17, 9, 28)
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas can use `datetime.datetime` or `pd.Timestamp` objects depending what you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# datetime objects
historic_date = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)  

date_str = '2020-01-01'
historic_date2 = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')  

# Timestamp objects
historic_date3 = pd.to_datetime(date_str)  
historic_date4 = pd.Timestamp(date_str) 
historic_date5 = pd.Timestamp(historic_date)
```